# Persist login data from subdomain Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

On my app every user logs from *subdomain.myapp.com*, but i have a special case which is more complex because the log is from *www.myapp.com* and then I need to redirect the user to *subdomain.myapp.com/somePath*
The problem is that obviously the session data is discarded by the browser because the login was made over *'www.'* and not over *'subdomain.'*. I need to persist this data when redirection is done.

How can i handle this situation? I only need this flow in the case i mentioned, not in whole app

I use devise gem for authentication.

Answer (score 0):

In **Rails** for every request from browser a method **[subdomains](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-subdomains)** is provided to collect all **subdomains** in an array.

Returns all the subdomains as an array, so **["dev", "www"]** would be
     returned for **"dev.www.rubyonrails.org"**.

You can probably collect all the subdomains in **application controller** as request variable is provided there and use them accordingly in other controllers.

**[Subdomains in Rails 3](http://railscasts.com/episodes/221-subdomains-in-rails-3)** will be a good **Railcast** to refer though.